# Paypal payflow pro 10002 error?

Tags: php, paypal

Am getting following error when i moved from local server to live server. It works perfectly on local server..

```
DoDirectPayment failed: Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => 2014%2d09%2d19T07%3a17%3a50Z [CORRELATIONID] => 2989510fbe4d6 [ACK] => Failure [VERSION] => 51%2e0 [BUILD] => 12896494 [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002 [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Authentication%2fAuthorization%20Failed [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You%20do%20not%20have%20permissions%20to%20make%20this%20API%20call [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error )
```

this is my request URL,

$nvpStr = "&PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&AMT=$amount&CREDITCARDTYPE=$creditCardType&ACCT=$creditCardNumber".
   "&EXPDATE=$padDateMonth$expDateYear&CVV2=$cvv2Number&FIRSTNAME=$firstName&LASTNAME=$lastName".
   "&STREET=$address1&CITY=$city&STATE=$state&ZIP=$zip&COUNTRYCODE=$country&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";

Comment: It seems like you are not passing the API credentials while making the API call as I also tried to make an API call without the credentials and got the same error . Can you check that credentials are being passed with the API call?

Comment: Thank you @Eshan i forgot to update my live database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume

- You are still using the sandbox endpoint : `https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp`
  You will need to use `https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp` for LIVE.
- Check if you enter a valid/non-empty API Username/Password/Signature.